# Group by range DATIME of 2h up or down - Mysql

Tags: mysql, select, datetime

Well, I have a table with some columns that some of these are repeated, but the time is not exactly the same, I need to do a group by that has a range of 2 hours.

Notice that all the fields marked in black repeat, but the datetime field may differ by a few minutes, so I need to make a group by joining everyone within that two-hour interval.

[image]

It would be something like: `SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY sinistro, prefixo, data` **AND horaIfull_oco range 2h up or down**

He would join all those who had a maximum of two hours apart. I have already researched and found nothing, if anyone knows how to do.

Comment: Show some sample output with more rows of input. If `A (.5hr) -> B (.5hr) -> C` do you want A,C somehow in the same group. How do you distinguish groups. Are rows duplicated?

Comment: @danblack So, with each new sinistro/ prefixo there, they will have UP TO 3 records, one of each person, one is an inspector, one of a driver and another of a person who stays in the office, but the time they launch there will almost never be the same, understand? It is not the child's registration time, it is the time they put in, there may be a difference of minutes or even hours, because they do not talk so there may be this divergence, but these 3 lines must belong to the same group

Comment: @danblack The grouping can not be by day as there may be 2 sinistro/ prefixo of the same day but at different times, with a divergence of at least 10h from the previous one, so that already does not belong anymore that group, you see?

Comment: @danblack In the group I need everyone who has approximately 2h of difference both up and down, join in the result

Comment: @danblack I asked the same question in stackoverflow and had a single query response: `SELECT *, floor(HOUR(horaIfull_oco) / 2) AS two_hour FROM table GROUP BY inclusao_oco, sinistro, prefixo, data, DATE(horaIfull_oco), two_hour`, when testing functioned, but after other tests, I saw that it does not hold, because dividing the hours there by 2 does not group everything, imagining that there was a record of **9h and one of 10h, int (9/2) = 4, int (10/2) = 5**, they would not group together

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did:

`SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY sinistro, prefixo HAVING horaIfull_oco BETWEEN SUBTIME(horaIfull_oco, '02:30:00') and ADDTIME(horaIfull_oco, '02:30:00')`

Comment: Hi Woton, sorry to say this, but this can't be right. Please have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry Woton, but your answer has several issues.

First of all, your usage of `GROUP BY` is not right. With `GROUP BY` you collapse several rows of a group to one. To get a meaningful result, all columns of your `SELECT` clause must either be included in the `GROUP BY` clause, or an aggregate function like `MIN()` or `AVG()` or `SUM()` has to be applied on it. Otherwise a random row of this group is displayed. So a `SELECT * FROM foo GROUP BY bar` is as good as always wrong. To make sure, you're doing it right, you could execute `SET GLOBAL sql_mode = CONCAT(@@global.sql_mode, ',ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY');` (for further information you can read this part of the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by))

The second issue with your query is, that the `HAVING` clause is a filter on the result of `GROUP BY`. Filters on columns that you are grouping by would be in the `WHERE` clause. Filters in the `HAVING` clause include an aggregate function, like `HAVING SUM(foo) > 5000`.
When you don't use an aggregate function, again a random row is used. Your `HAVING` clause therefore actually filters nothing at all. `x` is always greater than `x - 5` and `x` is always smaller than `x + 5`.

A filter that would work in your case (though I don't think this is what you want) would for example be `HAVING TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, MIN(horaIfull_oco), MAX(horaIfull_oco)) <= 150`. This isn't what you want, right?

If I understood you correctly, you want to build a group when consecutive rows are within a certain timerange, right? For this we would have to generate a column first, which we can later use to group on.

Let's do that.

Here's your query, explanation follows:

```
SELECT sinistro, prefixo, data
/*whatever else you need*/
, MIN(horaIfull_oco), MAX(horaIfull_oco), MIN(id_oco) AS id_oco, GROUP_CONCAT(inclusao_oco) AS incl 
FROM (
    SELECT 
    t.* 
    , @group_number := IF(
        @prev_sinistro != sinistro 
        OR @prev_prefixo != prefixo 
        OR @prev_data != data 
        OR TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, @prev_horaIfull_oco, horaIfull_oco) >= 150
        , @group_number + 1 
        , @group_number) AS gn 
    , @prev_sinistro := sinistro
    , @prev_prefixo := prefixo
    , @prev_data := data 
    , @prev_horaIfull_oco := horaIfull_oco
    FROM your_table t 
    , (SELECT @prev_sinistro := NULL, @prev_prefixo := NULL, @prev_data := NULL, @prev_horaIfull_oco := NULL, @group_number := 0) v 
    ORDER BY sinistro, prefixo, data, horaIfull_oco
) sq 
GROUP BY sinistro, prefixo, data, gn
```

First thing to notice, in a relational database there is no order of rows unless you specify it. So we `ORDER BY` the columns we want to use in our `GROUP BY` in the outer query and then by the timestamp/datetime column. The goal is, that we can use variables to access the previous row.
We don't want to execute the queries `SET @prev_sinistro := NULL; SET @prev_prefixo := ...` everytime before we execute the main query, so we initialize the variables in a subquery aliased with `v` here.
Then, every time `sinistro` or `prefixo` or `data` is different from the previous row, or when the difference between the previous rows `horaIfull_oco` and the value for this column in the current row is greater than 150 minutes, we increment the `@group_number` variable, if not we don't (we just assign the current value of the variable to the variable).
With `@prev_prefixo := sinistro` and so on we assign the value of the current row to the variable. It's important, that this is done after the `IF()` function. The `SELECT` clause is processed sequentially. When the next row is processed, the variables still hold the value of the previous row.

In the outer query finally, we can group by the generated `gn` column.

EDIT: To meet your further requirements, you could do this:

```
SELECT sinistro, prefixo, data, MIN(horaIfull_oco), MAX(horaIfull_oco)
FROM (
    SELECT 
    sinistro, prefixo, data, horaIfull_oco 
    , @group_number := IF(
        @prev_sinistro != sinistro 
        OR @prev_prefixo != prefixo 
        OR @prev_data != `data`
        OR TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, @prev_horaIfull_oco, horaIfull_oco) >= 150 
        OR DATE(@prev_horaIfull_oco) != DATE(horaIfull_oco)
        , @group_number + 1
        , @group_number) AS gn 
    , @prev_sinistro := sinistro
    , @prev_prefixo := prefixo
    , @prev_data := `data`
    , @prev_horaIfull_oco := horaIfull_oco
    FROM ocorrencia t 
    , (SELECT @prev_sinistro := NULL, @prev_prefixo := NULL, @prev_data := NULL, @prev_horaIfull_oco := NULL, @group_number := 0) v 
    ORDER BY sinistro, prefixo, data, horaIfull_oco
) sq 
GROUP BY sinistro, prefixo, data, gn;
```

EDIT 2:

So, I excluded `data` and used this query:

```
SELECT sinistro, prefixo -- , data
/*whatever else you need*/
, MIN(horaIfull_oco), MAX(horaIfull_oco), GROUP_CONCAT(id_oco) AS id_oco
FROM (
    SELECT 
    id_oco,
    sinistro, prefixo, /*data,*/ horaIfull_oco
    , @group_number := IF(
        @prev_sinistro != sinistro 
        OR @prev_prefixo != prefixo 
        -- OR @prev_data != data 
        OR TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, @prev_horaIfull_oco, horaIfull_oco) >= 150
        OR DATE(@prev_horaIfull_oco) != DATE(horaIfull_oco)
        , @group_number + 1 
        , @group_number) AS gn 
    , @prev_sinistro := sinistro
    , @prev_prefixo := prefixo
    -- , @prev_data := data 
    , @prev_horaIfull_oco := horaIfull_oco
    FROM ocorrencia t 
    , (SELECT @prev_sinistro := NULL, @prev_prefixo := NULL, @prev_data := NULL, @prev_horaIfull_oco := NULL, @group_number := 0) v 
    -- having id_oco in (254, 277)
    ORDER BY sinistro, prefixo, /*data,*/ horaIfull_oco
) sq 
GROUP BY sinistro, prefixo, /*data,*/ gn
```

Regarding your problems with id_oco 254 and 277, when you include

```
OR DATE(@prev_horaIfull_oco) != DATE(horaIfull_oco)
```

in the `IF()` function, these 2 records are in separate groups, if you don't they are in the same group because they are within the 2.5 hours range.

If you still have problems, please provide the desired result based on your sample data as well, to avoid further confusion.

Comment: I'm half nub, I did not quite understand what you actually did kkkk, sorry, I executed your query here and it gave practically the same result that I got with mine, only had a problem, if for example a record had its datetime for `2018- 11-12 00:07:00` and the other the `2018-11-11 23:07:00` they do not join, even being within range

Comment: And in my case, it does not really matter what order they come from, like, no matter which of the records is chosen to be shown within the group, the most important thing is that they unite

Comment: @WotonSampaio I edited my answer to meet this requirement. Is there anything special, you don't understand?

Comment: In that last one that sent, I did the test and did not group any more kkkk, ah and a little thing that I noticed, at the end there, take the group by data for just in this example that I mentioned she will do it, since they are of different dates

Comment: I'm sorry, I have a little trouble understanding your last comment.

Comment: It's because my English is not very good, lol, I'm sorry.

Comment: I said that with the last query that put, I did the test here and did not group any other results  :/

Comment: Can you share your sample data so I can see where the problem is? Maybe on http://sqlfiddle.com ?

Comment: Of course, I copied the whole sql to pastebin, I could not use what happened to me, so just copy the sql code there: https://pastebin.com/EeE5yUkP

Comment: Hi @WotonSampaio I had a few typos in there. Please try again with the query furthest down in my answer. In my test it works now. And note, that you use a case insensitive character set. `ABC1234_19112018` is considered the same as `Abc1234_19112018`.

Comment: The same error was repeated when the dates are of different days but still satisfy the range of hours, see lines with id 254 and 277, they do not join

Comment: And remember to take the 'data' column from group by, for this reason cited

Comment: Do I understand you correctly, that when the dates differ, they should be in different groups? Cause that is what they do.

Comment: Not exactly, because what really matters in this query is the range of hours, and as in that case I told you of these 2 records, they are of different dates but your time interval satisfies the proposed condition

Comment: But then the first query is already right? I fixed the typo, please try this query again.

Comment: It unites all the others, except for this specific case that I said

Comment: Good morning @WotonSampaio , I edited my answer again. Please have a look.

Comment: Hey dude, I tested your new query and the problem persists, the 2 records still do not join even satisfying the condition of> = 2:30h or <= 2: 30h

Comment: Again, I don't know what you mean by that. It probably would be best, if you could provide the desired result in your question.

Comment: @WotonSampaio So, no more feedback? Is your problem solved?